# What is the difference between puppetserver 1.1.3 vs puppet-server 3.8.6-1?

Tags: installation, puppet

I'm trying to setup puppet master. I installed puppetlabs in my CentOS 7 box using:

`$ sudo rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm`.

Now, when I try to give `sudo yum install puppet-server`, it installs **puppet-server** 3.8.6-1 and also puppet 3.8.6-1.

But the [documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/install_el.html) asks to do `sudo yum install puppetserver` (Notice that the hyphen is missing before server). When I run this, it installs **puppetserver** 1.1.3-1 and puppet 3.8.6-1.

My question is - what is the difference between puppet-server and puppetserver. Some documentations ask to use puppet-server for e.g [this](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/install_fedora.html). Which one should I be using?

Please see these screenshots for more info:
[image: screenshot1] [image: screenshot2]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package name similarity is unfortunate, as these are completely different packages that provide similar functionality.

The `puppet-server` package is for a machine to run the original, Ruby / Rack puppetmaster service.  There's not a lot to this, as most of the necessaries are built in to the main `puppet` package.  It includes an internal Webrick server and can therefore run standalone, but is more often run in a Rack stack, such as Apache / Passenger, for better capacity and scalability.

The `puppetserver` package is for a machine to run the new, Java-based 'puppetserver' service endpoint for serving catalogs.  It still relies on the Ruby catalog builder underneath; only the client service piece is shifted to Java.

You can use either one, but not both.  `puppet-server` has the advantage of not requiring a Java stack underneath.  `puppetserver` performs better, but only with respect to the actual client service bits.  Catalog building is often the real bottleneck, and `puppetserver` relies on the same infrastructure as `puppet-server` for that.

Answer (score 0):

`puppetserver` is the right one to install. See here,

https://docs.puppet.com/puppetserver/2.3/install_from_packages.html

Also, if you want to know what they should be doing. This will make it clear which package contains the right stuff.
https://docs.puppet.com/puppetserver/2.3/services_master_puppetserver.html

`puppet-server` seems to be setting up example environments. Most likely a dummy package.

```
]$ rpm -qlp http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/products/x86_64/puppet-server-3.8.6-1.el7.noarch.rpm
/etc/puppet/environments
/etc/puppet/environments/example_env
/etc/puppet/environments/example_env/README.environment
/etc/puppet/environments/example_env/manifests
/etc/puppet/environments/example_env/modules
/etc/puppet/fileserver.conf
/etc/puppet/manifests
/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetmaster.service
/usr/share/man/man8/puppet-ca.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/puppet-master.8.gz
```

comapred to `puppetserver`

```
]$ rpm -qlp http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/products/x86_64/puppetserver-1.1.3-1.el7.noarch.rpm
/etc/logrotate.d/puppetserver
/etc/puppetserver
/etc/puppetserver/bootstrap.cfg
/etc/puppetserver/conf.d
/etc/puppetserver/conf.d/ca.conf
/etc/puppetserver/conf.d/global.conf
/etc/puppetserver/conf.d/os-settings.conf
/etc/puppetserver/conf.d/puppetserver.conf
/etc/puppetserver/conf.d/web-routes.conf
/etc/puppetserver/conf.d/webserver.conf
/etc/puppetserver/logback.xml
/etc/puppetserver/request-logging.xml
/etc/sysconfig/puppetserver
/usr/bin/puppetserver
/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service
/usr/share/puppetserver
/usr/share/puppetserver/cli
/usr/share/puppetserver/cli/apps
/usr/share/puppetserver/cli/apps/foreground
/usr/share/puppetserver/cli/apps/gem
/usr/share/puppetserver/cli/apps/irb
/usr/share/puppetserver/cli/apps/ruby
/usr/share/puppetserver/ezbake-functions.sh
/usr/share/puppetserver/ezbake.manifest
/usr/share/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar
/usr/share/puppetserver/scripts
/usr/share/puppetserver/scripts/install.sh
/var/log/puppetserver
/var/run/puppetserver
```

Comment: It seems a bit ... circular .. to decide that puppetserver is the right one to install based on the docs of puppetserver itself.

Comment: that's exactly why, I spit the content of rpm. That maps the document to the package.

Comment: Evidently the RPM contents are misleading in this case.  The two packages in question are alternatives.  There is no clear-cut general answer to which one to use.